# How to convert one content type to another using Archetypes

Tags: python, plone, archetypes

I have a content type which which is a non-folderish content type, and I want to convert this content type into a folderish. Inside my content type there is a multifilefield. I read this link http://developer.plone.org/content/archetypes/converting-content-types.html about converting one content type to another. However, as I run it using browser view, the new content types were created, also the values of the old contents were copied except for the uploaded files handled by multifilefield, they are empty.

Here's my code inside browser view:

Updated:

```
def migrateaction(self):
    items=self.context.listFolderContents(contentFilter={"portal_type": 'myoldcontent'})
    for item in items:
        id = "%s-new" % item.getId()
        service = self.context.invokeFactory(
                    'mynewcontent',
                    id,
                    rp_category=item.getRp_category(),
                    familyname=item.getFamilyname(),
                    firstname=item.getFirstname(),
                    file=item.getField('file').getRaw(item))
    return 'Successfully migrated.'
```

My field definition for multifilefield:

```
MultiFileField('file',
    primary=True,
    languageIndependent=True,
    widget = MultiFileWidget(
    label= "File Uploads",
    show_content_type = False,)),
```

All field definitions are the same for both old and new content types.

Is there lacking in my code that caused the files not to be copied?

Comment: What is ``id`` in your code? ``id`` is a global function and should not be redefined, use ``id_`` as variable name. Maybe you should not cast to string in ``str(item.getFile())``? For getting the raw data you could use ``item.getField('file').getRaw(item)``.

Comment: Yes I forgot to insert this code on my post: id = "%s-new" % item.getId() before service = ...

Comment: Hi jone, i got an attribute error=> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'filename'

Comment: Did you change the file getter to getRaw? Can you update the question with the code you have now and add the schema-definition of the file field (of old and new, if different)?

Comment: It seems that the setter used in `invokeFactory` expects a different input that the `getRaw` of the `MultiFileField` returns. I'd try to remove the file from `invokeFactory` and do something like `service.getField('file').set(service, item.getField('file').getRaw(item))` beneath the `invokeFactory` statement.. Could you inspect what `getRaw` returns in this case and what a normal `get` returns?

Comment: Both item.getField('file').getRaw(item) and item.getFile() returns the same result which is a list of dictionary. The result would be: [{'get_size': 595284, 'icon': 'image.png', 'content_type': 'image/jpeg', 'file': <File at file>, 'filename': 'pic1.jpg'}, {'get_size': 879394, 'icon': 'image.png', 'content_type': 'image/jpeg', 'file': <File at file>, 'filename': 'pic2.jpg'}]